# Numpy calculation of eigenvectors is incorrect

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

I run the following in Python and expected the columns in E[1] to be the eigenvectors of A, but they are not. Only Sympy.Matrix.eigenvects() seem to do it right. Why this error?

```
A
Out[194]: 
matrix([[-3,  3,  2],
        [ 1, -1, -2],
        [-1, -3,  0]])

E = np.linalg.eig(A)

E
Out[196]: 
(array([ 2., -4., -2.]),
 matrix([[ -2.01889132e-16,   9.48683298e-01,   8.94427191e-01],
         [  5.54700196e-01,  -3.16227766e-01,  -3.71551690e-16],
         [ -8.32050294e-01,   2.73252305e-17,   4.47213595e-01]]))

A*E[1] / E[1]
Out[205]: 
matrix([[ 6.59900617, -4.        , -2.        ],
        [ 2.        , -4.        , -3.88449298],
        [ 2.        ,  8.125992  , -2.        ]])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The eigenvectors are correct, within an expected margin of error.
- What you discovered is that testing eigenvectors with element-wise division is a bad idea.

A better way is to compute the norm of the difference between `matrix*vector` and `eigenvalue*vector`.

NumPy performs computations in floating point arithmetics, limited to 52 bits of precision (double precision). This means any of its answers may contain numerical errors, at least of relative size 2**(-52) which is about 2e-16. So, when you see a number like 2e-16 coming from a calculation with numbers of size 1-3, the conclusion is: "that number should probably be zero, and the value we have for it is likely just noise". And if you divide by that number, noise is all you get.

SymPy, on the other hand, performs symbolic manipulations, so its answer (when it can get one) is exactly what the theory predicts.

Comment: Thanks for that, now it makes sense. Even if it had been exactly 0, 0/0 = inf, so this is always a bad idea :)

Comment: @user2908112 0/0 is undefined ;)

Answer (score 1):

From its docs:

> The number w is an eigenvalue of a if there exists a vector v such that dot(a,v) = w * v. Thus, the arrays a, w, and v satisfy the equations dot(a[:,:], v[:,i]) = w[i] * v[:,i] for i \in {0,...,M-1}.

With your matrix:

```
In [1]: A = np.array([[-3,  3,  2],
   ...:         [ 1, -1, -2],
   ...:         [-1, -3,  0]])
   ...:         
In [2]: w,v=np.linalg.eig(A)
In [3]: w
Out[3]: array([ 2., -4., -2.])
In [4]: v
Out[4]: 
array([[ -9.39932874e-17,   9.48683298e-01,   8.94427191e-01],
       [  5.54700196e-01,  -3.16227766e-01,   1.93473310e-16],
       [ -8.32050294e-01,  -4.08811066e-17,   4.47213595e-01]])
In [5]: np.dot(A,v)
Out[5]: 
array([[ -2.22044605e-16,  -3.79473319e+00,  -1.78885438e+00],
       [  1.10940039e+00,   1.26491106e+00,  -7.77156117e-16],
       [ -1.66410059e+00,   4.44089210e-16,  -8.94427191e-01]])
In [6]: w*v
Out[6]: 
array([[ -1.87986575e-16,  -3.79473319e+00,  -1.78885438e+00],
       [  1.10940039e+00,   1.26491106e+00,  -3.86946619e-16],
       [ -1.66410059e+00,   1.63524427e-16,  -8.94427191e-01]])
In [7]: np.dot(A,v)-w*v
Out[7]: 
array([[ -3.40580301e-17,   8.88178420e-16,   2.22044605e-16],
       [  8.88178420e-16,  -6.66133815e-16,  -3.90209498e-16],
       [ -2.22044605e-16,   2.80564783e-16,  -3.33066907e-16]])
In [8]: np.allclose(np.dot(A,v), w*v)
Out[8]: True
```

So, yes, the documented test is satisfied, within floating point limits.

`einsum` can be used to highlight the `i` axis in the `dot` calculation.

```
In [10]: np.einsum('...k,ki->...i',A,v)
Out[10]: 
array([[ -2.22044605e-16,  -3.79473319e+00,  -1.78885438e+00],
       [  1.10940039e+00,   1.26491106e+00,  -7.77156117e-16],
       [ -1.66410059e+00,   3.88578059e-16,  -8.94427191e-01]])
```

---

When I divide by `v` (element wise), the result matches the eigenvalues, 2 -4,-2, except where `v` and the `dot` are virtually 0 (1e-16 or smaller).

```
In [11]: np.einsum('...k,ki->...i',A,v)/v
Out[11]: 
array([[ 2.36234534, -4.        , -2.        ],
       [ 2.        , -4.        , -4.01686475],
       [ 2.        , -9.50507681, -2.        ]])
```